# How to execute curl -k -O curl -k -O "https://x.y.z.a/etc/abc.tgz" in Ansible

Tags: curl, https, ansible

How to execute curl -k -O curl -k -O "https://x.y.z.a/etc/abc.tgz" in Ansible 
I am new to ansible and would like to know how to make a curl request with -k and -O option in Ansible

This is what i have, what have i done wrong ?

hosts: '{{ host }}'

uri:

```
  url:  https://_my_url

  method: GET

  validate_certs: no

  tags: copy_source_code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
- name: Download abc.tgz
  get_url:
    url: https://x.y.z.a/etc/abc.tgz
    dest: /scratch/abc.tgz
    validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_url](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html) Ansible module with the `validate_certs: no`option